# 400 error when trying to send post request with image through angular

Tags: angular, spring, image, post, http-status-code-400

I am trying to send a post request through an angular UI that I built but I get the following error:

```
    core.js:6456 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/upload", ok: false, …}
error: {timestamp: "2021-07-17T19:59:09.036+00:00", status: 400, error: "Bad Request", path: "/upload"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/upload: 400 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/upload"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Below is my component.ts file:

```
  onFileSelected(event: any){
    console.log(event)
    this.imageFile = event.target.files[0]
  }

  //send post request to MySQL
  uploadImage(){
    const fd = new FormData(); 
    fd.append('image',this.imageFile)
    this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8080/upload",fd)
      .subscribe(res=>{
        console.log(res);
      })
  }
```

My HTML file:

```
<input type="file" class="file-input" (change) = "onFileSelected($event)"
       #fileUpload>

<div class="file-upload">

    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="upload-btn"
      (click)="fileUpload.click()" style="position:relative;top:25px;"  >
        <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon> 
    </button>

    <button mat-button style="position:relaive;left:1px;" (click) = "uploadImage()">Upload file</button>
</div>
```

And my backend service:

```
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder uploadImage(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Original Image Byte Size - " + file.getBytes().length);
        model img = new model(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getContentType(),
                compressBytes(file.getBytes()));
        userRepository.save(img);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Why am I receiving this error? It looks like everything is correct to me and the post request also goes through in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error,

```
fd.append('image',this.imageFile)
```

should be

```
fd.append('imageFile',this.imageFile)
```

to match with the nomenclature specified in the backend service.